# powershell script to list AD users that dont have access to a particular AD group

Tags: powershell

I need a PowerShell script that can list AD users who don't have access to a particular AD group.

Comment: What do you mean they don't have access to a group? What have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter out users whos not are members of particular group. Like so:

```
$dn = Get-ADGroup 'YourGroupName' | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object {-not $_.MemberOf.Contains($dn) }
```